# Odoo 12 How to use render_qweb_html?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-12

Hi I'm trying to create html from template in Odoo 12. I know from previous Odoo 8 we can use

```
html = self.env['report'].get_html(self, 'my_addon.my_template')
```

`get_html` method is no longer supported in Odoo 12. I read it was replaced by `render_qweb_html`

But when I tried like this

```
html = self.env['ir.actions.report'].render_qweb_html(self, 'my_addon.my_template')
```

Odoo respond with

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'`

Am I using the method incorrectly? Can anyone point where I made the mistake? I have looked for samples in the addons folder, yet found none.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user templates `render` method.

```
self.env.ref('template_external_id').render(render_context)
```

For more information, you can follow the official documentation of [qweb](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/qweb.html#view-based).